# Chrome extension rejected

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently submitted a chrome extension and it got rejected saying "**Where possible, make as much of your code visible in the package as you can. If some of your app's logic is hidden and it appears to be suspicious, we may remove it.**"

My extension is to share music. It works in the below way (simplified explanation):

1. Create a group and add people.
2. Submit a youtube/soundcloud or any title and url.
3. Users in the group get notified.

I have not used any external libraries. My code is not minified. I am using bootstrap css from their cdn. The code is not fully commented because the function names are very much self explanatory.

The extension does send request to my server to save the title and url. But this should not be the reason for rejection.

This is my 5th chrome extension. My earlier extensions were submitted without any problem.

Any ideas or hints or suggestions ?

Comment: Try uploading it by creating another extension on your dashboard.  If that doesn't work, you can upload an empty extension, then issue updates that update the code part by part until you get the error again.

Comment: That's a super awesome idea. I will try that and update you. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly the external CSS.

Comment: also double-check that you are following all the rules of the content security policy https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not tech support. [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue with my extension, after I read Marc's comment I suppose to upload it as new extension. That really work for me

> Try uploading it by creating another extension on your dashboard. If that doesn't work, you can upload an empty extension, then issue updates that update the code part by part until you get the error again. – Marc Guiselin

and check if there any external links for js css or fonts, which are not comply with [Google's Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)